# how to parse this html data into php array?

Tags: php, html, parsing

i receive data in this form, i want to parse this html data in to php array.

```
<table class="qprintable" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="600">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="300" valign="top">
<table class="qprintable2" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" border="0" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr class="phead">
<td colspan="2">
<b></b>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<div class="first"></div>
<div></div>
<div>2009jobs.agile@gmail.com</div>
<br>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<br>
<br>
<div></div>
<div class="last"></div>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<div class="first"></div>
<br>
<div></div>
<br>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class="last">&nbsp;</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr width="290">
<td valign="top" colspan="2">
<div class="first"></div>
<div></div>
<div class="last"></div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
<td width="300" valign="top">
<table class="qprintable2" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" border="0" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr class="phead">
<td colspan="2">
<b></b>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<div class="first"></div>
<div></div>
<div>aerosoft.career@rediffmail.com</div>
<br>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<br>
<br>
<div></div>
<div class="last"></div>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<div class="first"></div>
<br>
<div></div>
<br>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class="last">&nbsp;</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr width="290">
<td valign="top" colspan="2">
<div class="first"></div>
<div></div>
<div class="last"></div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Ask for JSON data instead. This one looks pretty ugly.

Comment: Have you tried something, or do you simply want someone to write your code for you?

Comment: @papaiatis i guess he can't ask 'cause he's just trying to steal some kind of data from another website.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php. Also see this tutorial http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/html-parsing-and-screen-scraping-with-the-simple-html-dom-library/ on nettutsplus

Comment: @k102 Yeah, he's probably trying to do that..

Comment: Whoever wrote that HTML should be shot - it is terrible.

Answer (score 1):

This one very ugly table ... but if you insest they are 3 solutions

Using http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Wrote this simple code :

```
    var_dump(parseUglyTable($table)) ;
    function parseUglyTable($table)
    {
        $html = str_get_html($table);
        $data = array(); 

        foreach($html->find('tr') as $row) {


            if($row)
            {
                $td = $row->find('td',0);

                $text = str_replace(array("<div>","</div>","&nbsp;"), "\n", $td->plaintext);
                $text = explode("\n", $text);

                foreach($text as $value)
                {
                    $value  = trim($value);
                    if(empty($value))
                        continue ;

                    $data[]  = $value ;
                }
            }
        }
        return $data;
    }
```

Output

```
    array
    0 => string '2009jobs.agile@gmail.com' (length=24)
    1 => string '2009jobs.agile@gmail.com' (length=24)
    2 => string 'aerosoft.career@rediffmail.com' (length=30)
```

Using **preg_match_all**

I figured that its only email address that exist in that ugly table ....  see http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php for more information with is much more efficient

Why use a **Tank or Guy to kill a rat** ??? just ask for JSON or XML format

I hope this helps

Thanks
:)

Answer (score 0):

Make a string from it and php explode it by "\n"